# Is there a way to execute a command in Postgres that conditionally trigger or not trigger the trigger function previously setup?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, google-cloud-sql

For example, I have a `posts` table that hold user posts information and I have `postlikes` table that hold each like for a post.

I have setup a trigger for the `postlikes` whenever a record is added (INSERT) or removed (DELETE) from it. Below is the trigger whenever user unlike a post (DELETE a record):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decrement_post_like_count() 
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
BEGIN 
UPDATE posts SET lks=lks-1, upd=DATE_TRUNC('millisecond', localtimestamp) WHERE pid=OLD.pid;
RETURN OLD;
END;
$$;
```

Add Trigger to a DELETE event which invoke the above function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_post_unlike 
AFTER DELETE ON postlikes
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION decrement_post_like_count();
```

Basically whenever a record is removed from `postlikes` table, then the trigger will reduce the like count (lks) by 1 from the corresponding post in the `posts` table. And there is another trigger setup which increases the count in the corresponding post in `posts` table whenever a record is added in `postlikes` table, but it is similar code so I don't display it here.

But now I want to be able to execute DELETE on the `postlikes` table without invoking the trigger, but I want to keep the trigger functions well. This is because I want to implement a post delete function, which should delete the post with all its corresponding likes. And of course, I don't want the trigger to fire in vain because we are deleting the post.

So is there probably a flag a could set that won't trigger this function and if the flag is not set then it will trigger the function.

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347756/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-update-triggers-from-being-triggered-within-a-delete-a) but I'm not sure if I want to use this kind of workaround, it is quite tedious or unnatural for this case.

I'm open to suggestions and other solutions.

Comment: DELETE != INSERT != UPDATE. Your trigger can choose when to fire. (and the function has acces to PG_TRG (sp?))

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to show the other part of code which link the trigger to an event. fixed in the question. So I have a trigger on INSERT and another one for DELETE (as shown in the question).

Comment: You could choose to call a different function on the DELETE event. Or let the function differentiate between types of event.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if I want to delete a row there is only one command DELETE that I can call right? So is there other command/event I can use to remove a record / row?